# Java: String.substring() with long type parameters

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a large string (an RSS Article to be more precise) and I want to get the word in a specific startIndex and endIndex. String provides the substring method, but only using ints as its parameters. My start and end indexes are of type long.

**What is the best way to get the word from a String using start and end indexes of type long?**

My first solution was to start trimming the String and get it down so I can use ints. Didn't like where it was going. Then I looked at [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) but didn't find anything. Any good solutions?

Thank you.

---

**Update:**

Just to provide a little more information.

I am using a tool called [General Architecture for Text Engineering (GATE)](http://gate.ac.uk/) which scans a String and returns a list of Annotations. An annotation holds a type of a word (Person, Location, etc) and the start and end indexes of that word .

For the RSS, I use [ROME](https://rome.dev.java.net/), which reads an RSS feed and contains the body of the article in a String.

Comment: Why don't you read your data set in chunks and use the regular substring(int,int)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big exactly are these strings?

Comment: Do you really get an RSS article of 8 GB??

Comment: @Sagar Yeah, I thought of that too. But I thought maybe there is a better way (not sure exactly how better :P).

Comment: @Pointy & @Roman :S Never crossed my mind to actually calculate the size, but the thing is, I use a library that scans a text and gives me indexes of certain words (not the actual words!). These indexes are of type long. I'm pretty sure that it's not THAT big...

Comment: Hmm..., an RSS article of 400 million words, I knew they were beating up the professional writers, but I am pretty sure the writers are not aware of the extent of the publishers ambitions :-).

Comment: OK OK... So basically I cast the long to an int and I'm OK.....

Comment: @pek sounds like it :) it would be interesting if the indexes are big enough to not fit in an int

Comment: @posdef Yeah, I didn't actually think of that at all... :P Kinda regret asking....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no point doing this on a String because a String can hold at `2^31 - 1` characters.  Internally the string's characters are held in a char[], and all of the API methods use `int` as the type for lengths, positions and offsets.

- The same restriction applied to StringBuffer or StringBuilder; i.e. an `int` length.
- A StringReader is backed by a String, so that won't help.
- Both CharBuffer and ByteBuffer have the same restriction; i.e. an `int` length.
- A bare array of a primitive type is limited to an `int` length.

In short, you are going to have to implement your own "long string" type that internally holds its characters in (for example) an array of arrays of characters.

(I tried a Google search but I couldn't spot an existing implementation of long strings that looked credible.  I guess there's not a lot of call for monstrously large strings in Java ...)

By the way, if you anticipate that the strings are never going to be this large, you should just convert your `long` offsets to `int`.  A cast would work, but you might want to check the range and throw an exception if you ever get an offset >= `2^31`.

Answer (score 1):

A `String` is backed by a `char[]`, and arrays can only be indexed with `int`s (and can consequently only hold 2<sup>31</sup> characters). If you have `long` indexes, just cast them to `int`s - if they're larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, your program is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use a `java.io.Reader`. This class supports the methods `skip(long n)` and `read(char[] cbuf)`. But please note they return a `long` (how many bytes were skipped / read), so you need to call those methods in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be better not to use `String` but `StringReader`.

Comment: Hmmm... I know StringBuffer and StringBuilder, but never heard of StringReader. Could you expand please? I don't see any substring methods.